# GCM Sends Empty Messages Whenever A User Register

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm having a really annoying problem, whenever a user register in my app ( send the token to my database ), gcm sends an empty message.

I managed to make a workaround fix by "if(!Message.contains("sometext"))" but the idea of receiving and waking up the device isn't a good idea .

When the user install and open the app for the first time, the app sends the token to a mysql database, that's it .. it doesn't do anything else, only sends the token .

How am i sending the message? via a dashboard, i'm sending the message via "topic" so i can send the message to everyone without selecting every token one by one ( i know the 1000 limit ) .

How can i fix this problem ?

PHP : [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Sending the token :

```
    @Override
public void onDeviceRegisted(String token) {
    boolean isReg = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isReg",true);
    if(isReg){
        GCMManager.getInstance(this).subscribeTopic("global");
        editor.putBoolean("isReg",false).apply();
        // This will send the token via POST method using Retrofit library .
        SendToken(token);
    }
}
```

And in a service, i'm making a notification from the push .

Comment: have you tested on android if you receive well the gcm id before sending it to the database?

Comment: Yup, I'm using a gcm library "fastgcm" called, you can find it on github, i'm checking first if it's a valid token by length, then i'm sending it to the database.

Comment: what are you using on the server side, PHP? did I understand well, you don't know how to push a message to your devices?

Comment: Wait what, no .. mate i'm getting empty messages that i didn't send, those messages are getting pushed every time a user send his token to the database, yes it's in PHP .

Comment: sorry I understood you bad before... :) can you show some code? (the part with notifications, android) I think the problem is not gcm ...maybe that library 'fastgcm' can be the issue, why you don't implement gcm without using additions libs? (just saying)

Comment: Well, i thought using a library will make it easier, that's what it did actually. But i don't think the problem is in the library, which code would you like to see? the sending token or making a notification ?

Comment: I would like to see all the parts of code from which you push the notifications in android

Comment: Check the op again please :)

Comment: Well you showed me how you are sending the token, but I would like to see how you notify in android, how you call your notification to be build...Because you have to see in your BroadCastReceiver or IntentService class what are you receiving, and then according to information you push the notification...